# How do you create a Scala collection of content in a Play template?

Tags: playframework, scala-collections, twirl, playframework-2.5

I'm sure I'm missing the obvious but is there a way to create a collection of Html objects to pass to a Play template like `@(title: String)(content: Seq(Html))`? I am trying to dynamically generate a group of tab pages where each Html object is the body of the tab.

Where my confusion lies is with how to create the Seq(Html) in the template. 
Something like `@main("Home") Seq({...},{...})` doesn't work and using `@(title: String)(contentTab1: Html)(contentTab2: Html)` and  `@main("Home") {...}, {...}` defeats the purpose.

Something like:

Tab content(`tab.scala.html`):

```
@(content: Html, tab: models.Tab, isActive: String)
<section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel @isActive" id="fixed-tab-@tab.id">
      <div class="page-content">@content</div>
</section>
```

Main template (`main.scala.html`):

```
@main(title: String, tabs: List[models.Tab])(contentSeq: Seq[Html])
```

Page template:

```
@(tabs: List[models.Tab])
@main("title", tabs) {
    <!-- tab1 content -->
} {
  <!-- tab2 content -->
}
```

*ignore bad design of matching `Seq[Html]` and `List[models.Tab]` sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled Play templates are basically just functions (or rather, objects with an `apply(...)` method), so assuming you have a single (partial) template for the tab content you can just apply it to the tab data using `map`, e.g:

Main template (`main.scala.html`):

```
@main(title: String, tabs: Seq[Html])(content: Html)

<h1>@title</h1>
<ul class="tabs">
   @tabs.map { tab =>
     @tab
   }
</ul>
@content
```

Tab content (`tab.scala.html`):

```
@(name: String)

<li>@name</li>
```

So each page template would look something like:

```
@(title: String)

@main(title, Seq("tab1", "tab2", "tab3").map(name => views.html.tab(name)) {
    <p>This is some content</p>
}
```

... or if you have more than one tab partial:

```
@main(title, Seq(views.html.tab1("tab1"), views.html.tab2("tab2"))) {
    <p>This is some content</p>
}
```

Yet another way is to render each tab as a [reusable block](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-blocks) and pass them to the master template as a sequence:

```
@(title: String)

@tab1 = {
    <li>Content for tab 1</li>
}

@tab2 = {
    <li>Content for tab 2</li>
}

@main(title, Seq(tab1, tab2)) {
    <p>This is some content</p>
}
```

Comment: This is close, although I still am hoping to pass multiple content blocks as each tab may have a different layout. Something like:

Comment: Sorry - can't add formatted comments - edited question above

Comment: @geeforce could you expand your question with that info (properly formatted)

Comment: @geeforce I have expanded the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes it looks like a single parameter list should work fine.

```
@(title: String, contents: Seq[String])
```

You can find more information on the [play framework website](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates).